# getElementById still the "safe" DOM manipulation method

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Excluding IE6-7, is `getElementById()` still the safe bet to access DOM elements, or are browsers so up to date now that all available `getElement(s)...` methods work just fine?

Comment: The `getElementsByTagName` routine works fine in IE6.

Comment: This is why people use libraries like jQuery.  So they don't need to worry about this.  That being said, I've heard of any DOM methods, other than the "new" `getElementsByClassName`, having issues in browsers.  As long as you have a modern browser, you're fine.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName (see "Browser Compatibility")

Comment: @apsillers: The question originally said "`getElementsByTagName` and friends", so he was always talking about all of them.

Comment: That was my intention from the start. Edited to clarify. Posting on SE is an exercise in painful precision!

Comment: Unless you're using IE <=8 (if you are, I'm really sorry), then you should have nothing to worry about: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) is safe but can return multiple items.

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns only one element (All HTML Id's should be unique) and should be used when you know the the identifier of the `DOM` element.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the users of your product/app and what browsers they are likely to have.

As a rule I normally look at the web stats or google analytics reports for browser usage, by version. Then if older pre HTML5 browsers appear to make up over 2.5% of the total like for example Internet Explorer 8 then I'd stick to getElementById or getElementsByTagName.

Luckily we all have jQuery at hand which will default to native functions like getElementsByClassName if they are available in the browser, otherwise it uses it's own version.